# Incrementar y calcular el precio según orden jerárquico en php

Tags: php

Tengo una función que consulta un precio mediante **case** para un respectivo caso de una liga a otra que funciona bien,

```
case 'bronce1-bronce2':
$price = 6;
```

pero la lista de precios se ha hecho muy extensa y necesito saber si existe una función en PHP que sirva para calcular tan sólo la cantidad de divisiones de una liga y obtener el precio de una forma más eficaz, actualmente he hecho este array

```
$precios = [
 "Hierro 1" => "2",
 "Hierro 2" => "2",
 "Hierro 3" => "2",
 "Hierro 4" => "2",

 "Bronce 1" => "3",
 "Bronce 2" => "3",
 "Bronce 3" => "3",
 "Bronce 4" => "3",

 "Plata 1" => "4",
 "Plata 2" => "4",
 "Plata 3" => "4",
 "Plata 4" => "4",

 "Oro 1" => "5.5",
 "Oro 2" => "5.5",
 "Oro 3" => "5.5",
 "Oro 4" => "5.5",

 "Platino 1" => "7",
 "Platino 2" => "7",
 "Platino 3" => "7",
 "Platino 4" => "7",

 "Diamante 1" => "9",
 "Diamante 2" => "9",
 "Diamante 3" => "9",
 "Diamante 4" => "9"
]
```

Y el antiguo código es este

```
function get_price($league_1, $league_2)
{
    $product = $league_1 . '-' . $league_2;
    switch ($product)
    {
    //bronce
        case 'bronce5-bronce4': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 6;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-bronce3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 6;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-bronce2': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 6;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-bronce1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 6;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-plata5': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 7;
            break;
        case 'plata5-plata4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 7;
            break;
        case 'plata4-plata3': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 7;
            break;
        case 'plata3-plata2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 7;
            break;
        case 'plata2-plata1': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 7;
            break;
        case 'plata1-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 8;
            break;
        case 'oro5-oro4': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 8;
            break;
        case 'oro4-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 8;
            break;
        case 'oro3-oro2': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 8;
            break;
        case 'oro2-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 8;
            break;
        case 'oro1-platino5': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 11;
            break;
        case 'platino5-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 11;
            break;
        case 'platino4-platino3': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 11;
            break;
        case 'platino3-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 11;
            break;
        case 'platino2-platino1': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 11;
            break;
        case 'platino1-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 13;
            break;
        case 'diamante5-diamante4': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 16;
            break;
        case 'diamante4-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 18;
            break;
        case 'diamante3-diamante2': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 20;
            break;
        case 'diamante2-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 22;
            break;
        case 'diamante1-maestro': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 27;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A PLATA 5
        case 'bronce5-plata5': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 30;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-plata5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 24;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-plata5': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 18;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-plata5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 12;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-plata5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 11;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A PLATA 4
        case 'bronce5-plata4': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 37;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-plata4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 31;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-plata4': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 25;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-plata4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 19;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-plata4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 13;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A PLATA 3
        case 'bronce5-plata3': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 49;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-plata3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 43;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-plata3': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 37;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-plata3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 31;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-plata3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 25;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A PLATA 2
        case 'bronce5-plata2': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 56;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-plata2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 50;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-plata2': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 44;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-plata2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 38;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-plata2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 32;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A PLATA 1
        case 'bronce5-plata1': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 63;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-plata1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 57;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-plata1': // 5 -> 4
            $price = 51;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-plata1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 45;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-plata1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 39;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A ORO 5
        case 'bronce5-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 60;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 54;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 48;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 42;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 36;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A ORO 4
        case 'bronce5-oro4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 68;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-oro4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 60;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-oro4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 52;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-oro4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 44;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-oro4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 36;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A ORO 3
        case 'bronce5-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 84;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 78;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 72;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 66;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 60;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A ORO 2
        case 'bronce5-oro2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 92;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-oro2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 86;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-oro2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 80;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-oro2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 74;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-oro2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 68;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A ORO 1
        case 'bronce5-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 100;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 94;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 88;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 82;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 76;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A PLATINO 5
        case 'bronce5-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 100;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 94;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 88;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 82;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 76;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A PLATINO 4
        case 'bronce5-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 108;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 100;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 92;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 84;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 76;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A PLATINO 3
        case 'bronce5-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 130;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 124;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 118;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 112;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 106;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A PLATINO 2
        case 'bronce5-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 141;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 135;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 129;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 123;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 117;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A PLATINO 1
        case 'bronce5-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 152;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 146;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 140;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 134;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 128;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A DIAMANTE 5
        case 'bronce5-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 150;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 144;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 138;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 132;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 126;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A DIAMANTE 4
        case 'bronce5-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 166;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 160;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 154;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 148;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 142;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A DIAMANTE 3
        case 'bronce5-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 200;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 194;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 188;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 182;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 176;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A DIAMANTE 2
        case 'bronce5-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 218;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 212;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 206;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 200;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 194;
            break;
            //DE BRONCE X A DIAMANTE 1
        case 'bronce5-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 238;
            break;
        case 'bronce4-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 232;
            break;
        case 'bronce3-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 226;
            break;
        case 'bronce2-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 220;
            break;
        case 'bronce1-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 214;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A ORO 5
        case 'plata5-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 35;
            break;
        case 'plata4-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 28;
            break;
        case 'plata3-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 21;
            break;
        case 'plata2-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 14;
            break;
        case 'plata1-oro5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 13;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A ORO 4
        case 'plata5-oro4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 43;
            break;
        case 'plata4-oro4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 36;
            break;
        case 'plata3-oro4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 29;
            break;
        case 'plata2-oro4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 22;
            break;
        case 'plata1-oro4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 15;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A ORO 3
        case 'plata5-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 59;
            break;
        case 'plata4-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 52;
            break;
        case 'plata3-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 45;
            break;
        case 'plata2-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 38;
            break;
        case 'plata1-oro3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 31;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A ORO 2
        case 'plata5-oro2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 67;
            break;
        case 'plata4-oro2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 60;
            break;
        case 'plata3-oro2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 53;
            break;
        case 'plata2-oro2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 46;
            break;
        case 'plata1-oro2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 39;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A ORO 1
        case 'plata5-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 75;
            break;
        case 'plata4-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 68;
            break;
        case 'plata3-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 61;
            break;
        case 'plata2-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 54;
            break;
        case 'plata1-oro1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 47;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A PLATINO 5
        case 'plata5-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 70;
            break;
        case 'plata4-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 63;
            break;
        case 'plata3-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 56;
            break;
        case 'plata2-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 49;
            break;
        case 'plata1-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 42;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A PLATINO 4
        case 'plata5-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 81;
            break;
        case 'plata4-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 74;
            break;
        case 'plata3-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 67;
            break;
        case 'plata2-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 60;
            break;
        case 'plata1-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 53;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A PLATINO 3
        case 'plata5-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 100;
            break;
        case 'plata4-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 93;
            break;
        case 'plata3-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 86;
            break;
        case 'plata2-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 79;
            break;
        case 'plata1-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 72;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A PLATINO 2
        case 'plata5-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 111;
            break;
        case 'plata4-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 104;
            break;
        case 'plata3-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 97;
            break;
        case 'plata2-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 90;
            break;
        case 'plata1-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 83;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A PLATINO 1
        case 'plata5-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 122;
            break;
        case 'plata4-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 115;
            break;
        case 'plata3-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 108;
            break;
        case 'plata2-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 101;
            break;
        case 'plata1-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 94;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A DIAMANTE 5
        case 'plata5-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 120;
            break;
        case 'plata4-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 113;
            break;
        case 'plata3-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 106;
            break;
        case 'plata2-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 99;
            break;
        case 'plata1-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 92;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A DIAMANTE 4
        case 'plata5-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 136;
            break;
        case 'plata4-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 129;
            break;
        case 'plata3-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 122;
            break;
        case 'plata2-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 115;
            break;
        case 'plata1-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 108;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A DIAMANTE 3
        case 'plata5-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 159;
            break;
        case 'plata4-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 152;
            break;
        case 'plata3-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 145;
            break;
        case 'plata2-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 138;
            break;
        case 'plata1-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 131;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A DIAMANTE 2
        case 'plata5-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 177;
            break;
        case 'plata4-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 170;
            break;
        case 'plata3-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 163;
            break;
        case 'plata2-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 156;
            break;
        case 'plata1-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 149;
            break;
            //DE PLATA X A DIAMANTE 1
        case 'plata5-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 197;
            break;
        case 'plata4-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 190;
            break;
        case 'plata3-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 183;
            break;
        case 'plata2-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 176;
            break;
        case 'plata1-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 169;
            break;
            //DE ORO X A PLATINO 5
        case 'oro5-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 40;
            break;
        case 'oro4-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 32;
            break;
        case 'oro3-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 24;
            break;
        case 'oro2-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 17;
            break;
        case 'oro1-platino5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 16;
            break;
            //DE ORO X A PLATINO 4
        case 'oro5-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 51;
            break;
        case 'oro4-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 43;
            break;
        case 'oro3-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 35;
            break;
        case 'oro2-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 27;
            break;
        case 'oro1-platino4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 19;
            break;
            //DE ORO X A PLATINO 3
        case 'oro5-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 73;
            break;
        case 'oro4-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 65;
            break;
        case 'oro3-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 57;
            break;
        case 'oro2-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 49;
            break;
        case 'oro1-platino3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 41;
            break;
            //DE ORO X A PLATINO 2
        case 'oro5-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 82;
            break;
        case 'oro4-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 74;
            break;
        case 'oro3-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 66;
            break;
        case 'oro2-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 58;
            break;
        case 'oro1-platino2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 50;
            break;
            //DE ORO X A PLATINO 1
        case 'oro5-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 93;
            break;
        case 'oro4-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 85;
            break;
        case 'oro3-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 77;
            break;
        case 'oro2-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 69;
            break;
        case 'oro1-platino1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 61;
            break;
            //DE ORO X A DIAMANTE 5
        case 'oro5-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 90;
            break;
        case 'oro4-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 82;
            break;
        case 'oro3-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 74;
            break;
        case 'oro2-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 66;
            break;
        case 'oro1-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 58;
            break;
            //DE ORO X A DIAMANTE 4
        case 'oro5-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 105;
            break;
        case 'oro4-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 97;
            break;
        case 'oro3-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 89;
            break;
        case 'oro2-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 81;
            break;
        case 'oro1-diamante4': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 73;
            break;
            //DE ORO X A DIAMANTE 3      
        case 'oro5-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 128;
            break;
        case 'oro4-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 120;
            break;
        case 'oro3-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 112;
            break;
        case 'oro2-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 104;
            break;
        case 'oro1-diamante3': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 96;
            break;
            //DE ORO X A DIAMANTE 2    
        case 'oro5-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 146;
            break;
        case 'oro4-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 138;
            break;
        case 'oro3-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 130;
            break;
        case 'oro2-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 122;
            break;
        case 'oro1-diamante2': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 114;
            break;
            //DE ORO X A DIAMANTE 1   
        case 'oro5-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 166;
            break;
        case 'oro4-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 158;
            break;
        case 'oro3-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 150;
            break;
        case 'oro2-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 142;
            break;
        case 'oro1-diamante1': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 134;
            break;
            //DE PLATINO X A DIAMANTE 5
        case 'platino5-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 55;
            break;
        case 'platino4-diamante5': // 4 -> 3
            $price = 44;
            break;

        default:
            die('unknown');
    }
    return $price;
```

Comment: El precio se calcula de alguna manera, hay alguna formula o es un valor arbitrario???

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Es una formula, pero quiero hacer que se calcule tipo de bronce 3 a plata 4 (es ascendente) que vendrían a ser 3 divisiones de bronce, tipo $valordebronce x 3

Comment: Son 3 pk despues del bronce3 vendrian 3 divisiones para llegar a plata4??

Comment: Así es. En el primer código los puse en el órden correcto, son de menor a mayor para subir de una liga a otra

Answer (score 1):

Creo que conviene cambiar la lógica de tu programa, llevando el modelo de datos a una representación que además sea portable. Esto consiste en algo muy simple: cambiar todos tus case por un array que asocie los elementos a los precios.

Cuando haya situaciones nuevas, sólo tienes que agregarlas al array. Además, es probable que esto sea más acorde a una realidad mucho más profunda de tu aplicación que puede ser la base de datos.

Haciendo esto, la función quedaría así:

```
function get_price($league_1, $league_2)
{
    $product = $league_1 . '-' . $league_2;
    $relPrecioLigas=array (
                        'bronce5-bronce4'  =>6,
                        'bronce4-bronce3'  =>6,
                        'bronce3-bronce2'  =>6,
                        'oro1-platino5'    =>11,
                        'platino5-platino4'=>11,   
                        'bronce2-plata4'   =>19,
                        'bronce1-plata4'   =>13,
                    );
    $price=isset($relPrecioLigas[$product]) ? $relPrecioLigas[$product] : 0;
    return $price;
}
```

He puesto sólo algunos valores para prueba. La función recibe los valores y los busca en el array, devolviendo el precio. He puesto un control, mediante un operador ternario, para que devuelva `0` cuando se le pase una clave que no existe (esto haría las funciones del `default` en un bloque `switch ... case`.

Haciendo eso, tienes en `$relPrecioLigas` una representación estructurada de tu modelo de datos, y además portable y muy fácil de adaptarse a nuevas situaciones.

Hagamos algunas pruebas:

```
echo get_price('platino5','platino4').PHP_EOL;    
echo get_price('fake','fake').PHP_EOL;    
echo get_price('bronce2','plata4').PHP_EOL;
```

**Salidas:**

```
11
0
19
```

---

#### Fiddle

Puedes ver una <kbd>**[`DEMOSTRACIÓN`](https://rextester.com/NIRDT82949)**</kbd> del código en línea y hacer pruebas sobre él.

---

> #### NOTA
>
> Viendo que tienes una array de precios con unos valores decimales.
>   Imagino que el precio se calcula de alguna manera. Esa lógica podría
>   ser incorporada, quizá, al mismo array `$relPrecioLigas` y hacer algo
>   mucho más refinado. En ese sentido este enfoque de estructurar mejor
>   los datos abre una puerta muy interesante que podría ayudarte no
>   solamente a ahorrarte decenas de líneas de código, sino a escribir un
>   programa más claro, más intuitivo, mejor organizado y más portable.